# Test YahooSite by using CodedUI testing

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I started testing simple applications. I use Coded UI testing by Visual Studio 2012. I want to make working importing parameters from CSV file I added to the project. When I run my test the username parameters read from this file are ok, but what about the password?

```
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
{       
       this.UIMap.EnterEmailParams.UILoginEditText = TestContext.DataRow["Email"].ToString();
       this.UIMap.EnterPasswordParams.UIPasswdEditPassword =TestContext.DataRow["Password"].ToString();

        this.UIMap.OpenYahooSite();
        this.UIMap.ClickMail();
        this.UIMap.EnterEmail();
        this.UIMap.EnterPassword();
        this.UIMap.ClickSignInn();

        this.UIMap.ClickClose();
}
```

My test failed: `Length of the data to decrypt is invalid`.

My csv file looks:

```
Email, Password  
nij@yahoo.com,jujupopp  
nihu@yahoo.co,huhukikk
```

Can anyone suggest me what to do with my problem with password. Just enter the username, close Yahoo, and then goes to the next iteration.

Comment: Is there maybe a formating on the pw-input so that the display don't show the real length of pw-string? For example: jujupopp becomes ****

Comment: How can I check that?I changed csv file with different parameters and save it, but the same problem again.

Comment: Type in your pw on yahoo-site and you will see if number of displayed letters equal to the number of typed in letters. You can also set a breakpoint at the place where the coded ui test compares the pw´s to see what exactly will compare. At the moment I am far a way form a visual studio, so I can tell you exactly what to do, but step in to the method EnterPassword() (and futher) and you will find the responsible assert.

Comment: It is possible that Coded UI saw that it was a password field and did some special processing. I would compare the bodies of the `EnterEmail` and `EnterPassword` methods and, if necessary, alter the password one to be similar to the email one. (Do not make he changes in the `uimap.designer.cs` file, obviously.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this.UIMap.PasswordDetailsParams.UIPasswordEditPassword = Playback.EncryptText(TestContext.DataRow["password"].ToString());

Comment: Maybe you can add a bit more detail in your answer? Why you did it that way, what were the advantages over other solutions available? Maybe format your code so it is readable.